# Read a variable JSONB and put it into columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.4, sql-function

I am reading a postgresql database which has a jsonb column, the length of the jsonb is variable.
I would like to read the jsonb column and make a table from it:

```
type | jsonb
---------------------------
 a   |[0,-0.9996,300,...] length -> 18
 b   |[1,89,10,...] length -> 16
 a   |[2,-0.79,200,...] length -> 18
...
```

I need a function that gives you the following tables depending on the input,
Input = "type a":

```
Status | energ   | time ... until the 18th value
-----------------------
0      | -0.9996 | 3000
```

Input = "type b":

```
SerialNumber | reference | status ... until the 16th value
---------------------------------
1            | 89        | 10
```

I am trying with something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.test()
  RETURNS entry
 AS $$
 DECLARE
    dato jsonb;
    len integer;
BEGIN
  FOR tsi,dato IN
    SELECT ts,sgdata 
    FROM ingecms.samplegroup 
    WHERE samplegroup.cyclicgroupid = 7
    ORDER BY 1
    LOOP
    len=jsonb_array_length(dato);
    FOR x in 0..len-1 LOOP
        entry = ---Reading the jsonb object from position 0 until len
    END LOOP;
    RETURN entry
   END LOOP;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * from pg_temp.test();
```

Comment: Where do the column names come from? BTW: Your data is not valid JSON. Did you mean "[0,-0.9996,300,...]" (do you have an array?). Do all type a JSON values have exactly 18 values or do the lengths differ within the types.

Comment: The length differs from the types, the names of the columns come from another query. I have a JSON data I meant to put "[0,-0.9996,300,...]"

Answer (score 0):

For valid json, you could use the function [jsonb_array_elements_text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM jsonb_array_elements_text('[0,-0.9996,300]'::jsonb);
```

Comment: This statement gives me the next error: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.
I need to parse more than 1 jsonb entry

Comment: I guess the question is not expanding the values into rows but into columns.

Comment: The above query works fine in version 9.5 and in version 13, just tested both. Your query must be different, could you show us?

Comment: SELECT  jsonb_array_elements_text((SELECT sgdata FROM ingecms.samplegroup 
  INNER JOIN edlcygroupsV ON samplegroup.cyclicgroupid=edlcygroupsV.cyclicgroupid
  WHERE samplegroup.cyclicgroupid = 7
  ORDER BY 1));

Comment: If i put "LIMIT1" it works, but i need to do it for more than 1 jsonb,

SELECT  jsonb_array_elements_text((SELECT sgdata FROM ingecms.samplegroup 
  INNER JOIN edlcygroupsV ON samplegroup.cyclicgroupid=edlcygroupsV.cyclicgroupid
  WHERE samplegroup.cyclicgroupid = 7
  ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1));